# Regular expression to exclude 2 words

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

I am using REGEX in JAVA, and I need to check if an String has one WORD without some certain words right before and after it.

I managed to create a regular expression wich excludes the word after:

```
.*WORD(?! AFTER).*
```

With this expression, the string *"bla bla WORD AFTER bla bla"* will not match, but the string "bla bla WORD bla bla" will match.

I need the same behaviour for the previous word also. For example, the String     *"bla bla bla BEFORE WORD AFTER bla bla bla"* shouldn't match, but the string "bla bla WORD bla bla" should.

I tried this:

```
.*(?!BEFORE )WORD(?! AFTER).*
```

Although the expression doesn't give any error, it doesn't have the expected behaviour. Instead, it works exactly the same as the first expression (without *(?!BEFORE )*). 
Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "it's not working", you need to be more specific.  Is it matching something it shouldn't?  Not matching something it should?  Give specific examples.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger You are right. I edited the question. Thanks ;)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still unclear on something.  Should the string "bla BEFORE WORD bla" match?  What about "bla WORD AFTER bla"?

Comment: What is text is *"bla bla BEFORE, AFTER bla bla"* (with a comma)?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger  It should match only if WORD appears alone: "bla WORD bla". The answer of Olsli is correct anyway. But thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (negative lookbehind (see [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) for class [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special)):

```
.*(?<!BEFORE )WORD(?! AFTER).*
```

Comment: It works properly. I tried many things but I didn't see the negative lookbehind. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've tested this in Sublime text with all the examples given above and it works - well done :)